# Batch > file.txt to one file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

I have a batch code like this

```
COMMAND1 > file.txt
COMMAND2 > file.txt
COMMAND3 > file.txt
```

And it is overriding file.txt I need it to add it not replace it can any one help

**Result**

```
Before:

result3
```

-

```
After:

result1
result2
result3
```

Comment: I believe you can use >> to append to the end of a file.

Comment: So i would use COMMAND1 >> file.txt

Comment: Yeah that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks didn't think it would be that simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `>>` to append to the file. Cheers